# Node 'Undefined' Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, undefined

So I currently am trying to get the following to simply return the variable obj. It is located in "auth.js"

```
module.exports = {
  cas_login: function(ticket) {
    var obj;
    cas.validate(ticket, function(err, status, username) {
      if (err) {
        // Handle the error
        obj={status: false, username: null};
      } else {
        // Log the user in
        obj={status: status, username: username};
        }
      });
    if(obj){
      return obj;
    }
  }
};
```

This is then being called (as a test) by "console.log(auth.cas_login(ticket));" I know that everything is properly linked as auth.cas_login will work when is simply have it return {hello : ticket}, however for some reason the cas.validate is causing issues. I am new to asynchronous language and assume it likely has something to do with that.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  The assignment to `obj` happens inside the callback to `validate`.  But your `return obj` happens before the callback is run.

Comment: So what would be the best way to go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions like this pop up a lot on S.O. but before the question gets closed, I'll walk you through the async behavior, since you're new to it.

Let's run `cas_login`.  It has three statements:

1. Declare `obj`, initialize to `undefined`.
2. Call `validate`.  This runs asynchronously, meaning the execution will be queued up to run when the scheduler says it can.  But it cannot run now, because `cas_login` is not done yet.
3. `if (obj) return obj`.  Well here `obj` is undefined, which is falsy, so the `if` statement is skipped.  This means the function ends without ever hitting a `return` statement.  And in JS, this means the function returns undefined.

What you need to do is make `cas_login` async. You tried to make it sync.  Define it to take a callback of its own, one which processes the value `obj`. Along these lines (untested):

```
module.exports = {
  cas_login: function(ticket, callback) {
    cas.validate(ticket, function(err, status, username) {
      if (err) {
        callback({status: false, username: null});
      } else {
        callback({status: status, username: username});
      }
    });
  }
};
```